# Oracle SQL loader references

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Can you guys give me some good references on Oracle SQL loader. I did Google, none of the search I found was useful

Comment: Can I have some more references on the Sql Loader?

Comment: searching on google for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loader is covered in the Database Utilities book, which quite well written:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/toc.htm

Personally, I'd use External Tables instead of SQL*Loader nowadays...

Comment: The advantage of SQL*Loader is, that it can be used from a client. For external tables you have to copy the input file to the server which is not always possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, of course. Some things can't be done with the loader, some things can't be done with external tables. But if you are new to the topic, the loader, it's control and log files are a lot to learn compared to the rather simple (and fast) external tables...

Comment: Isnt't the control file for an external table the same as a control file for SQL*Loader?

Comment: Firstly, it's stored in the database, not somewhere on somebodies client. Secondly, it describes only the format of the file. Transformations and id generation is done in proper SQL instead of some funny extra language...

Comment: Another difference I recall is that external tables could not deal with stream data in 10.2 at least -- EOL records were required I believe.

Comment: The preprocessor should be able to handle this? But this is getting silly. OP asked about a first reference to documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Below are the some useful references for **SQL*Loader**-:

1. [SQL*Loader Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm#i1004619)
2. [Table-Specific Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-227B995D-72A8-42EE-ADD9-350B8A229495.htm#SUTIL1106)
3. [Loading Data into Empty Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-63D25923-62F8-41A4-8062-662744CB1C84.htm)
4. [Loading Data into Nonempty Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-2F1B7E71-AE90-40CB-9A7F-B44187FD059C.htm)
5. [SQL*Loader Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm#i1007844)
6. [Parameter File](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm#i1005781)
7. [Options Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_control_file.htm#i1004788)

Last but not the least, most helpful frequently asked questions about SQL*Loader.

- **[SQL*Loader FAQ](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ)**